# Fragment のアプリがすぐに落ちてしまう

Tags: android, java, android-fragments

お世話になります。

Android の勉強を再開して、手始めに Fragment を使ってみようと思い、このページ「[AndroidStudioの標準デザインパターンで分かるFragment入門](http://qiita.com/Hoshi_7/items/bee2588397348a4e0105)」でトライしてるのですが、うまく行かず、質問させていただきました。

```
unfortunately アプリ名 has stopped
```

logcat にもなんのエラーも出ないので、どうしたものかと思っております。

関係ありそうなソースも記載しておきます。

```java
package jp.co.shiratsu.testfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ImageFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ImageFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM_RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";
    private int mResourceId;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param resourceId
     * @return A new instance of fragment ImageFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int resourceId) {
        ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM_RESOURCE_ID, resourceId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ImageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mResourceId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM_RESOURCE_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResourceId);

        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

```java
package jp.co.shiratsu.testfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(position == 0){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, ImageFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.yukiyama))
                    .commit();
        }else{
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
        }


    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.co.shiratsu.testfragment" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MainActivity` が `OnFragmentInteractionListener` を実装していないからではないでしょうか。

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{
```

ご自身で以下のように書かれているので、`MainActivity` は `OnFragmentInteractionListener` を実装しないといけないと思います。

```
try {
    mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
}
```

`logcat` で見ると、以下のような `ClassCastException` エラーが出ていました。

```
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: jp.co.shiratsu.testfragment.MainActivity@41a24a28 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at jp.co.shiratsu.testfragment.ImageFragment.onAttach(ImageFragment.java:80)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
 01-14 18:38:49.952 E/AndroidRuntime(29904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
```

Comment: logcatに何も出なかったんですよね。。。ちょっとやってみます！

Comment: 出来ました！お恥ずかしい。。。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

下記のURL先に記載されているようにsetContentView()に問題がありそうですね。

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pVjYhUAaDtwJ:qiita.com/little/items/a14298ded25246c3de8f+&cd=1&hl=ja&ct=clnk&gl=jp

追記
　AcitvityのsetContentView()に設定するレイアウトファイルは合ってますね。失礼しました。